# Python : Add values of 'n' dictionaries with the same key and store into one dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dict as –

```
dict_1 = { 'A' : {'1029' : 3, '1039' : 5}, 'B' : {'1029' : 3, '1039' : 5}, 'C' : {'1008' : 1, '1029' : 3, '1039' : 8, '1050' : 1}, 'D' : {'1008' : 1, '1029' : 10, '1039' : 3}}
```

I want a result as an addition of all similar numbers. i.e.

```
result = {'1008' : 2, '1029' : 19, '1039' : 21, '1050' : 1}
```

Approach I have used :

I created a list with a dict_1 as

```
list_new = [ {'1029' : 3, '1039' : 5},  {'1029' : 3, '1039' : 5},  {'1008' : 1, '1029' : 3, '1039' : 8, '1050' : 1}, {'1008' : 1, '1029' : 10, '1039' : 3}]
```

Then I used below code:

```
    for i in range(0, len(list_new)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list_new)):
            if (i == 0 and j == 1):
                dict_12 = {k: list_new[0].get(k, 0) + list_new[1].get(k, 0) for k in set(list_new[0]) | set(list_new[1])}

            else:
                dict_13 = {k: dict_12.get(k, 0) + list_new[j].get(k, 0) for k in set(dict_12) | set(list_new[j])}
                dict_12.clear()
                dict_12.update(dict_13)
```

But its giving a wrong result.. If I will comment last 2 lines in above code, then it works fine for 3 iterations. But I want the code to run for 'n' iterations.

For it, I need to store the previous result. Can anyone please help me for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum_dict = {}
for d in dict_1.values():
    for key, val in d.items():
        if key in sum_dict:
            sum_dict[key] += val
        else:
            sum_dict[key] = val

>>> sum_dict
{'1050': 1, '1039': 21, '1029': 19, '1008': 2}
```